# how to connect Loki helm chart to my app in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, grafana-loki

I am new to Loki but all i want to do is to use it as simply as possible with helm.

I want to get the logs of my app witch is in kubernetes, but it seems that there is no instructions on how to do that. All I find is how to install Loki and to add it to Grafana as a datasource but I don't think that's what Loki is made for.

I simply want to track my app's logs in kubernetes so I am using Loki helm chart and all I can find about a custom config is this line:

```
Deploy with custom config

helm upgrade --install loki grafana/loki-stack --set "key1=val1,key2=val2,..."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After installing Loki you can set it as a data source for Grafana.
For more details you can follow this example :[Logging in Kubernetes with Loki and the PLG Stack](https://codersociety.com/blog/articles/loki-kubernetes-logging)

I hope that this can help you to resolve your issue .

Comment: this is helping but it doesn't has infos on how to get logs from my proper app ... but i find out than by just running Loki in the same cluster as the app , Loki will start getting the logs from my app .. so it worked , thanks